# Speeding up a nested loop in R

Tags: r, loops, logic, nested-loops, new-operator

As you can see from my username I am a complete beginner. I have searched for the answer to this question however I am struggling to find a working example that does anything similar to what I need. This code currently works however it looks like it might take over 64 hours to run.

This code is to help me identify how many active contracts there are on any given day over a 5 year period. my process at the moment is to loop through everyday between 2015-01-01 to 2020-10-05, and then loop through every row of data.frame to see if the start and end dates of the contract fall within the date being looped through.

```
big_data_new <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
     end_date start_date start_date_N end_date_N
1: 2017-03-16 2016-03-16        16876      17241
2: 2015-07-31 2015-07-08        16624      16647
3: 2016-08-02 2016-07-06        16988      17015
4: 2017-07-18 2017-05-31        17317      17365
5: 2016-10-28 2016-01-07        16807      17102
6: 2017-08-01 2017-06-29        17346      17379")
```

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

big_data_new <- big_data_new2

big_data_new$start_date <- lubridate:: parse_date_time(big_data_new$start_date, orders =  "d-b-Y")
big_data_new$end_date <- lubridate:: parse_date_time(big_data_new$end_date, orders =  "d-b-Y")



big_data_new = select(big_data_new, end_date, start_date)
big_data_new$start_date <- as.Date(big_data_new$start_date, "%d-%M-%Y")
big_data_new$end_date <- as.Date(big_data_new$end_date, "%d-%M-%Y")
head(big_data_new)


StartDate<-"2015-01-01"
EndDate<- "2020-10-05"
dates<-seq(as.POSIXct(StartDate, format="%Y-%m-%d"), as.POSIXct(EndDate, format="%Y-%m-%d"), by='days')
df = NULL



for (f in as.list(dates)){
 Between22 <- as.Date(f, format="%Y-%m-%d")
 class(Between22)
 
 count=0
 for(i in 1:nrow(big_data)){
   date_start <- as.Date(big_data$start_date_N[i], origin="1970-01-01")
   date_end <- as.Date(big_data$end_date_N[i], origin="1970-01-01")
   
   if (between(Between22, date_start, date_end) == TRUE){ 
     count=count +1
   }
   
 }
 
 df = rbind(df, data.frame(Between22, count))
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum/count between two dates in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57255851/sum-count-between-two-dates-in-r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)


big_data_new <- tibble::tribble(
     ~end_date, ~start_date, ~start_date_N, ~end_date_N,
"2017-03-16", "2016-03-16",        16876, 17241,
"2015-07-31", "2015-07-08",       16624, 16647,
"2016-08-02", "2016-07-06",        16988, 17015,
"2017-07-18", "2017-05-31",        17317, 17365,
"2016-10-28", "2016-01-07",       16807, 17102,
"2017-08-01", "2017-06-29",       17346, 17379)

## what are min starting and max ending date
date_range_min <- min(big_data_new$start_date_N)
date_range_max <- max(big_data_new$end_date_N)


## this definese the range of dates we are going through
date_vector <-   date_range_min:date_range_max
  
## create storage object which is large enough to contain all results !!
result_vector <- vector(mode = "integer", length = length(date_vector))


for (d  in seq_along(date_vector)) {
  
  ## logical tests: is date between any starting or ending date? 
  ## if so, each row  for which this is true will return TRUE 
  ## sum(TRUE) equals 1, 0 otherwise
  
  result_vector[[d]]   <- 
    sum(big_data_new$start_date_N <= date_vector[[d]] & big_data_new$end_date_N >= date_vector[[d]])
  
}

result_data_frame <- tibble::tibble(date = date_vector, number_of_contracts = result_vector)
result_data_frame %>% dplyr::mutate(date = lubridate::as_date(date))
```

One problem is that you loop through the rows of your dataframe which is unnecessary in this case. Another aspect is that you create a result object that is large enough to contain all the results. If you have a (very) large data set and you keep on 'growing' your result object this will lead to lower speed. I can highly recommend [Hands-on Programming in R](https://rstudio-education.github.io/hopr/speed.html)
where both points are illustrated. By the way: I could not properly execute your approach without changing variable names. Also the **df** data frame only had count = 0 as results when I tried.

**Edit**: When I managed to execute your code it took

```
Time difference of 17.04095 secs
```

to execute (without loading packages).

When I executed my solution it took:

```
Time difference of 0.916553 secs
```

without loading packages (with same time range as you).

Hopefully this will provide the speed increase that you asked for. If so, I was very glad to help!

Comment: Also I only used the numerical values of the dates that you provided because I assume comparing numeric values might work faster then comparing dates, but this is just a guess.

Comment: Maybe somebody could even measure and compare the speed of the two approaches? Would probably be very useful

Comment: Also, when I changed the starting date in your code from from to "2005-01-01" execution time doubles to **41.33378 secs**. When I change the starting date to "1970-01-01" in my code execution time increases to **1.013297 secs**

Comment: Chris this is amazing! you are some kind of Wizard. Thank you so much. :)