# Sum variable between dates in R?

Tags: r

How do you sum a value that occurs between two dates in R?

For example, I have two data tables, df1 has start and end dates, df2 has values corresponding to certain dates between the start and end dates in df1. I would like to sum the values in df2 between each Start and End date in df1 and record that information in df1.

```
df1 <- data.frame(Start = c('1/1/20', '5/1/20', '10/1/20', '2/2/21', '3/20/21'),
                 End = c('1/7/20', '5/7/20', '10/7/20', '2/7/21', '3/30/21'))

df2 <- data.frame(Date = c('1/1/20','1/3/20' ,'5/1/20','5/2/20','6/2/20' ,'6/4/20','10/1/20', '2/2/21', '3/20/21'),value=c('1','2','5','15','20','2','3','78','100'))
```

I have tried following the example at the following link that provides information on counting between two dates in R but I am struggling to apply it to the function sum. [Sum/count between two dates in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57255851/sum-count-between-two-dates-in-r)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a non-equi join in `data.table` after converting the date columns to `Date` class

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
setDT(df1)[df2, value := sum(value), 
        on = .(Start <= Date, End >= Date), by = .EACHI]
```

-output

```
df1
#        Start        End value
#1: 2020-01-01 2020-01-07     2
#2: 2020-05-01 2020-05-07    15
#3: 2020-10-01 2020-10-07     3
#4: 2021-02-02 2021-02-07    78
#5: 2021-03-20 2021-03-30   100
```

#### data

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, mdy) 
df2$Date <- mdy(df2$Date)
df2$value <- as.numeric(df2$value)
```