# how to create a new variable in df1 with the sum of a variable in df2 based on a start and end date in df1?

Tags: r, merge, data.table

The perfect answer to my question already exists as the first answer by @akrun to this question [Sum variable between dates in R?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/66894918/sum-variable-between-dates-in-r)

the answer by @akrun is exactly what I am looking for, but when I run the code with the example data in the original question I do not get a sum of the value column between the two dates, instead I get the last value in the date interval...

Any suggestions?

Example data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Start = as.Date(c('1/1/20', '5/1/20', '10/1/20', '2/2/21', '3/20/21'),"%m/%d/%y"), End = as.Date(c('1/7/20', '5/7/20', '10/7/20', '2/7/21', '3/30/21'),"%m/%d/%y"))
            
df2 <- data.frame(Date = as.Date(c('1/1/20','1/3/20' ,'5/1/20','5/2/20','6/2/20' ,'6/4/20','10/1/20', '2/2/21', '3/20/21'),"%m/%d/%y"),value=as.numeric(c('1','2','5','15','20','2','3','78','100')))
```

@akrun code:

```
 setDT(df1)[df2, value := sum(value), 
  on = .(Start <= Date, End >= Date), by = .EACHI]
```

Comment: can you add the output of the of what you're getting the post

Comment: You may need `setDT(df2)[df1, .(value = sum(value)), on = .(Date >= Start, Date <= End ), by = .EACHI]$value#
[1]   3  20   3  78 100`

Comment: Thank you @akrun, this is exactly what I was looking for! I am new to stack overflow, but as I understand it I cannot mark the question as solved on the basis of a comment. If you post this code as an answer, I can mark the question as solved based on that.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could do the join in reverse

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df2)[df1, .(value = sum(value)), 
     on = .(Date >= Start, Date <= End ), by = .EACHI]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `fuzzyjoin` solution: Key point is using `match_fun` function:

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(dplyr)

fuzzy_left_join(
  df2, df1,
  by = c(
    "Date" = "Start",
    "Date" = "End"
  ),
  match_fun = list(`>=`, `<=`)
) %>% 
  group_by(Start, End) %>% 
  summarise(sum = sum(value))
```

```
  Start      End          sum
  <date>     <date>     <dbl>
1 2020-01-01 2020-01-07     3
2 2020-05-01 2020-05-07    20
3 2020-10-01 2020-10-07     3
4 2021-02-02 2021-02-07    78
5 2021-03-20 2021-03-30   100
6 NA         NA            22
```

Comment: If you use the devel versin of `dplyr` `left_join(df2, df1, join_by(closest(Date >= Start), closest(Date <= End))) %>% group_by(Start, End) %>% summarise(Sum = sum(value, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')`